# How to configuring Reporting Server Database Configuration?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, configuration, reporting, configurationmanager

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ReportServer3.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(SqlConnection conn, String script, ICommandWrapperFactory commandWrapper)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(String connectionString, String script)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.SqlClientTools.SqlTools.ApplyScript(String connectionString, String script)
ClientConnectionId:66ed706c-8c3e-4f92-878e-c5a6ce4f68bc
Error Number:5118,State:1,Class:16
```

I tried creating a new report server database which the error posted in the problem detail

Comment: What about the error don't you understand?

Comment: From the docs *"Warning: Read/write data filegroups and log files are not supported on an NTFS compressed file system."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-and-physical-file-names